# Issue while Setting PID's to MPEGTS Mux

Tags: gstreamer, mpeg, mux

I am streaming a .ts file over UDP, by setting PID's for each stream.

This ts file contains, video and text streams.

I would like to set my own pid's to mpegtsmux as follows,

```
g_object_set (mMux, "prog-map", gst_structure_from_string ("program_map,sink_300=10,sink_303=10,sink_302=10,sink_301=10", NULL), NULL);
```

It is working fine sometimes, But sometimes i am getting the following error.

```
 BUS_MESSAGE :: Error : Stream on pad <ts-mux:sink_300> is not associated with any program

 BUS_MESSAGE :: Debug : mpegtsmux.c(1250): mpegtsmux_collected_buffer (): /GstPipeline:digital-pipeline/MpegTsMux:ts-mux
```

But when i used the pipeline, its working fine.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/home/uurmi/Desktop/final_release_2.0_cd_burn/source/system/soa/output/Most_VM_1.ts ! tsdemux name=demux program-number=10 demux.video_012c ! queue ! muxer.sink_300 mpegtsmux name=muxer prog-map=program_map,sink_300=10,sink_302=10,sink_303=10,sink_301=10 ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=192.168.2.217 port=8765 demux.metadata_012f ! queue ! muxer.sink_303
```

Why this error came? Is the above g_object_set is right, for setting prog-map property to Muxer?

And how to solve this error?

Comment: can anybody answer this?

Comment: can anybody help me?

Comment: can you post your .ts file somewhere?